# Is it possible to make alias for a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, alias

Assume in a winform application we have in `program.cs`:

```
static class Program
{
    public static SomeClass someClass;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //something
    }
}
```

so to use `someClass`in other classes in current Project we should access `Program.someClass`

the question is can we make an alias for `Program.someClass` like for example `c1` and use `c1` in code instead of `Program.someClass`?

Comment: No, besides creating a local var that holds a reference to it.

Comment: This very notion is counter-intuitive, IMHO. Even if possible (speaking in terms not pertaining to reference types and their potentially multiple alias' which occur symptomatically), it could only make maintenance of the code more problematic, and people write bad enough code as it is! It kind of calls for a mechanism which is, if nothing else, overkill, I think.

Comment: What's the point? You shouldn't be typing it all out by hand anyway; use Intellisense.

Comment: @Anonymous coward: even if you don't like the code, the question is clear and legal. I give +1 for annulating the downvote

Comment: @cody: the question is just about the possibility dude. I know it is not usefull.

Comment: +1, I think it's a good question, and think there is no way to do this, but if it was possible was funny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're just looking to alias it for wrist-friendliness, do it as an inline delegate, like this:

```
Func<SomeClass> c1 = () => Program.someClass;
```

But I agree that it makes your code less clear in most cases.

Comment: @HPT: `c1()` will return you that instance. So you can perform `c1().SomeClassMethod()` for example.

Comment: @HPT: it is still a dependency. How will you retrieve `c1` instance in `AnotherClass`? If you can access `c1` - then you can also access `Program.someClass`.

Comment: Why doing this? You can do it: `SomeClass c1 = Program.someClass`.

Comment: lambda arrows => generally sour readibility

Comment: Same as: public static SomeClass c1 () { return Program.someClass;} FYI, if you ever needed a short for long static class name you could write on top: using P = NameSpace_name.Program;

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to achieve something like macros in C/C++ and also want to get rid of "Program" as naming scope, I think you cannot do that in C#.

Comment: That's the plain truth.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass that object to each class that need to work with it

Comment: the question is just about the possibility dude. I know it is not usefull.

Comment: @HPT: programmers do solve **real tasks**. The better is to pass object. The world will be better if some one will use less static classes, thus write more flexible code.

Comment: +1 for better approach, but the question was just about my curiosity and I am looking for a way to do this not solving it by deleting the main problem :D

Comment: @HPT: I'm sure that any problem can be solved without such hacks ;-)